# Android photo gallery slow to recognize newly added image (caching issue?)

Tags: android, caching, photo

**Is there a method that needs to be called to notify the OS that a new image has been added to the photo gallery?**

I've got a camera application that allows a user to export images to a sub folder in the Android device's photo gallery.

The copy functionality works properly, but it can sometimes take anywhere from 10 seconds to 2 minutes for the gallery app to recognize that a new image has been added to the folder. And sometimes I need to exit the application, then return before it displays the new image. The behavior is the same whether I use the Samsung Gallery app or the Google photos app, which suggests it is an OS level cache.

I've verified the image is being written immediately within the device browser in Android studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the current item to the OS's cache by using the following code:

```
           // Add the file to the media database
            var f = new Java.IO.File(fileInTargetDirectory);
            var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMediaScannerScanFile);
            intent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(f));
            CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.SendBroadcast(intent);
```